# Passing a <tr> id to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery and I ran into a problem. I have a table with 50+ rows. Each is labeled with an id.

```
<tr id="51">
```

This id is the database id and I need to pass it to jQuery and submit it along with an AJAX request.

```
        $($location).click(function () {
            var $currentSelection = $(this);

            // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
            if($currentSelection.find('select').length > 0)
                return;

            $currentSelection.html('');

            $('<select id="selectLocation" onChange="locationSubmit()"/>')
                .attr('name', 'location')
                .append('<option>Location 1</option>', '<option>Location 2</option>', '<option>Location 3</option>')
                .appendTo(this);
        });
```

`locationSubmit()`

```
function locationSubmit(){
            var $selectLocation = $('#selectLocation').val();
            var $selectId = $(this).val('tr#id'); //stuck here
            alert($selectId);
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
                data: {
                        action: $selectLocation,
                        courseid: $selectId
                    },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                    }
            });
        }
```

the alert in `locationSubmit()` is returning [object Object]. How do I pass the value of `tr#id` to `locationSubmit()` and send it via AJAX?

EDIT - HTML

```
<tr id="51">
    <td><a href="/link/goes/here.php?course_id=5&id=51">course name</a></td>
    <td>
        <span class="rowStartDate" id="rowStartDate151">09/10/12</span> - 
        <span class="rowEndDate" id="rowEndDate151">09/14/12</span>
    </td>
    <td class="location">Location 2</td>
    <td class="status">open</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Starting an `id` with a numeral is technically invalid unless you're using HTML5.  For HTML4, [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) are the naming rules.  Run your HTML page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to be sure.

Comment: check my new edit, it maybe could be right or a step on the ladder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there is any good answer?

Test this:

```
$($location).click(function () {
        var $currentSelection = $(this);

        // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
        if($currentSelection.find('select').length > 0)
            return;

        $currentSelection.html('');

        $('<select id="selectLocation"/>')
            .attr('name', 'location')
            .append('<option>Location 1</option>', '<option>Location 2</option>', '<option>Location 3</option>')
            .appendTo(this);
    });
```

and replace your function with this:

```
$('body').delegate('#selectLocation', 'change', function(){

        var $selectLocation = $(this).val(); //Edited here also
        var $selectId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); //edited here
        alert($selectId);
//The AJAX here        
});
```

And as you see, your function is gone and replaced by the delegate, which seemed to work great! The [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) is a very good function that is working all the time, even if elements are created after the DOM is ready. It's listening all the time

**Edited**
Check the second code part.

Comment: This returns "undefined". I have a `.click` function creating the `<select>`, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: There is no 'this' defined. You only call a function. Not connected.

Comment: Thanks Max. That almost works. It returns the id of the first `<tr>` on the page (51). When I click on other items, it returns the same id

Comment: HTML sample added above in original question.

Comment: So, I missed a very vital part. In the delegate function I referred to `#selectLocation` but it should only be `this`, without any quotes, see my new edit!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $selectId = $('#selectLocation').parent("tr").attr("id")
```

But not to good practice to have ids only in numbers.

**AND !!**

You are creating multiple `ids`. Can be defined just one per document.

use:

```
$($location).on("click" ...
```

to use dynamic objects

change:

```
$('<select class="selectLocation"
```

then

```
$(".selectLocation").change(function()
{
   var $selectLocation = $(this).val();
   var $selectId = $(this).parent("tr").attr('id'); 
   alert($selectId);

        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
            data: {
                    action: $selectLocation,
                    courseid: $selectId
                },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
                }
        });


}
```

Comment: This returns "undefined". I have a `.click` function creating the `<select>`, could that be causing the issue?

Comment: and how is defined is `$location` ?

Comment: It's defined at the top of my script using, `var $location = $(".location");`

Comment: Sure. But do you have proper tag as location? (th || td)

Comment: This will not work, because the element is created after the document is ready... Or maybe I was to fast during the reading